# Java: How to create a room with people having random birthdays?

Tags: java, math, probability, object-oriented-database, birthday-paradox

This is my second day on Java. I came across an interesting question on the Birthday Paradox.

1. Generate a random birthday.
2. Create a Person with a random birthday.
3. Build a function to check if two persons have the same birthday.
4. Create a Room with a given number of persons n.
5. Build a function to check if at least two persons in a Room have the same birthday.

However, I am stuck on how to create a 'Room' with 'persons' and then comparing the persons' birthdays.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you for your effort and time! :)

```
    class Person {
    int age;
    }

    class Room {
    int Person;
    }

    public class BirthdayParadox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 364);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 364);
        long r = Math.round(x);
        long s = Math.round(y);

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.age = (int) r;

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.age = (int) s;

        if (person1.age == person2.age) {

            System.out.println("Same!");
        }

        else if (person1.age != person2.age) {
            System.out.println(person1.age + " " + person2.age);
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: How does this differ from your earlier question, which was closed as "too broad"?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `Room` class should probably contain a `List<Person>` or an array of Person (Person[]).
2. The constructor of `Person` should accept a `dateOfBirth` parameter, or, to make it more simple, you can accept an integer between 1 and 365 which represents the date of the birthday not including the year, since that's all you care about. Don't call that member `age`, since it has nothing to do with age.
3. You want to use `(int)(Math.random() * 365) + 1`, which would give you integers between 1 and 365. You don't need to use `Math.round()`.

Answer (score -1):

For this, all you would need is an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of integers, with each index holding the birthday of one person.

For example, to hold the birthdays of 10 people, you would create an integer array of size 10.

```
int[] birthdays = new int[10];
```

You can the assign a value to an index of the array with the following:

```
birthdays[2] = (int)(Math.random() * 364);
```

The above code would assign the 3rd person's birthday to a random value.

To get the birthday of a person, use similar code to the following:

```
birthdays[1]
```

So, to print the 5th person's birthday, you would use

```
System.out.println(birthdays[4]);
```

Remember that arrays are 0-indexed, which means that the first value is 0 and the last is (size - 1). So for example, the 6th element is at index 5.